# Converting a space and tabulated separated table string nested in data frame to wide data in R

Tags: r, readr

I am struggling to convert a nested tabular and space delimited character string to wide data. My data looks something like this:

```
#Sample data
df <- tibble(id = 1:3, 
             text_table = c(NA,
                            "P1\tP2\tL1\n
                            M1\t15.09\t10.45\n
                            M2\t3040\t1959\n
                            M3\t0\t660\n",
                            NA))

df
# A tibble: 3 × 2
     id text_table                                                                                                                
  <int> <chr>                                                                                                                     
1     1  NA                                                                                                                       
2     2 "P1\tP2\tL1\n\n                            M1\t15.09\t10.45\n\n                            M2\t3040\t1959\n\n            …
3     3  NA
```

Using `read_table` from `readr` package I can convert a single line to a text string, but I would like to apply this to entire column (`text_table`) and then convert the data to none nested wide data.

```
library(readr)
read_table(df$text_table[2])
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  P1        P2     L1
  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 M1      15.1   10.4
2 M2    3040   1959  
3 M3       0    660
```

My desired output would look something like:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 7
     id P2_M1 P2_M2 P2_M3 L1_M1 L1_M2 L1_M3
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1  NA      NA    NA  NA      NA    NA
2     2  15.1  3040     0  10.4  1959   660
3     3  NA      NA    NA  NA      NA    NA
```

I don´t know how to apply the function `read_table`to all the column elements. Using `apply` and `lapply` have not worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’d first write a helper function to transform a single table to the format
you are after:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  id = 1:3,
  text_table = c(
    NA,
    "P1\tP2\tL1\n
    M1\t15.09\t10.45\n
    M2\t3040\t1959\n
    M3\t0\t660\n",
    NA
  )
)

read_text_table <- function(x) {
  if (is.na(x)) return(tibble())
  
  read_table(I(x)) |>
    pivot_wider(
      names_from = P1,
      values_from = c(P2, L1)
    )
}

read_text_table(df$text_table[2])
#> # A tibble: 1 × 6
#>   P2_M1 P2_M2 P2_M3 L1_M1 L1_M2 L1_M3
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  15.1  3040     0  10.4  1959   660
```

Because the function is going to be applied to each element in the column,
it needs to also gracefully handle an `NA` input. Here we just return an
empty tibble in that case.

Then use `rowwise()` to apply it to each element in the `text_table` column:

```r
tables <- df |>
  rowwise(id) |>
  summarise(
    read_text_table(text_table)
  )
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'id'. You can override using the `.groups`
#> argument.

tables
#> # A tibble: 1 × 7
#> # Groups:   id [1]
#>      id P2_M1 P2_M2 P2_M3 L1_M1 L1_M2 L1_M3
#>   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     2  15.1  3040     0  10.4  1959   660
```

Because the `read_text_table()` helper returns a 0-row data frame when there
is no table to read, we need a join to get the final result:

```r
df |>
  select(id) |>
  left_join(tables, by = "id")
#> # A tibble: 3 × 7
#>      id P2_M1 P2_M2 P2_M3 L1_M1 L1_M2 L1_M3
#>   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1  NA      NA    NA  NA      NA    NA
#> 2     2  15.1  3040     0  10.4  1959   660
#> 3     3  NA      NA    NA  NA      NA    NA
```